# How to process result of last command with awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have to count how many users were logged in each day of the week. I can get the data with the last command on the server, but how can I process it with awk? It is a long list of data, the name of the day is in the 4th column. I declared an array like this: t["Sun"]=0; t["Sat"]=0; etc, I can count it from a simple input from the terminal, but how can I use it on the output of last?

If I log in the server and type: last, I get a result like this, each row containing the name of the user, pts/something, ip address, day of the week, time etc:

```
user pts/0 address Mon etc.

user pts/1 address Wed etc.
```

I'd like an output like this:

```
Mon: 10 users were logged in

Tue: 20 user were logged in etc
```

My code is here, which works with an input from terminal:

```
awk '
        BEGIN { t["Sun"]=0; t["Sat"]=0; t["Fri"]=0; t["Thu"]=0; t["Wed"]=0; t["Tue"]=0; t["Mon"]=0; }
        { t[substr($4,i,3)]++;} 
        END {for(i in t) print i ": " t[i]}   
'$*
```

So far to an input in terminal like this:

```
aa ss dd Fri
a d g Mon
q w e Fri
```

gives the result:

```
Wed: 0
Tue: 0
Fri: 2
Thu: 0
Sat: 0
Sun: 0
Mon: 1
```

How can I use the awk command to process the output of last?

Comment: Your output of command(last of whichever command you are running) is not clear, please do edit in your post and let us know then.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide expected output that you can gt from your posted sample input, not output you'd get from some different input which is far less useful to us. Also, if you want to sum values by day, then provide an example that has more than 1 value per day.

Comment: A simplified version: `awk '{count[$4]++}END{for(j in count) print j ": " count[j]}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want something like:

```
last |
awk '
    BEGIN { split("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat",days) }
    { numUsers[$4]++ }
    END {
        for (dayNr=1; dayNr in days; dayNr++) {
            dayName = days[dayNr]
            printf "%s: %d users were logged in\n", dayName, numUsers[dayName]
        }
    }
'
```

so you always get output for every day, including days when no-one logged in, and the days are sorted in the weekday order you prefer.